# I've been trying to find ways to implement duplicates and sorting names in alphabetical order in csv file but it's just not working

Tags: python, csv, sorting, duplicates, spyder

I want to add a contact that already exists to detect a duplicate, something like:

```
for field in contact_fields:
            if contact_fields == field.strip():
                print("The contact already exists!")
            else:
                print("Contact saved successfully")
                break
```

Once they enter an existing name, it'll print out the if output. But for mine, it doesn't work.

As for sorting list/column alphabetically, the output of the contact list in the console is this:

```
--- Contact List ---
First Name       |Last Name      |Phone Number   |Email  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Amy      |Wood   |598456549      |amy@gmail.com  |



Zack     |Douglas        |6598243        |zack@gmail.com         |



Sally    |Kirsh  |9455426        |sally@gmail.com        |




Press any key to continue
```

I'm trying to get the first names sorted from
Amy
Sally
Zack

like the sorted contact list in any mobile phones.

Hopefully someone can find a solution

Here's the full coding:

```
#Contact Management System

import csv
# Define global variables
contact_fields = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", "Email"]
contact_database = "cms.csv"



def contact_menu():
    print("--------------------------------------")
    print("      Contact Management System       ")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("1. Add New Contact")
    print("2. View Contacts")
    print("3. Update Existing Contact")
    print("4. Delete Contact")
    print("5. Quit")


def add_contact():
    print("-------------------------")
    print("Add Contact Information")
    print("-------------------------")
    global contact_fields
    global contact_database

    # [ ['1','2'] ]
    contact_data = []
    for field in contact_fields:
        value = input("Enter " + field + ": ")
        contact_data.append(value)

    with open(contact_database, "a") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows([contact_data])

    print("Contact saved successfully")
    input("Press any key to continue")
    return


def view_contacts():
    global contact_fields
    global contact_database

    print("--- Contact List ---")

    with open(contact_database, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for x in contact_fields:
            print(x, end='\t |')
        print("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------")

        for row in reader:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end="\t |")
            print("\n")

    input("Press any key to continue")


def update_contact():
    global contact_fields
    global contact_database

    print("--- Update Contact ---")
    firstname = input("Enter their first name to update: ")
    firstname_contact = None
    updated_data = []
    with open(contact_database, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        counter = 0
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) > 0:
                if firstname == row[0]:
                    firstname_contact = counter
                    print("Contact Found: ",firstname_contact)
                    contact_data = []
                    for field in contact_fields:
                        value = input("Enter " + field + ": ")
                        contact_data.append(value)
                    updated_data.append(contact_data)
                else:
                    updated_data.append(row)
                counter += 1


    # Check if the record is found or not
    if firstname_contact is not None:
        with open(contact_database, "w") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(updated_data)
    else:
        print("Contact not found in the list")

    input("Press any key to continue")


def delete_contact():
    global contact_fields
    global contact_database

    print("--- Delete Contact ---")
    firstname = input("Enter their first name to delete: ")
    contact_found = False
    updated_data = []
    with open(contact_database, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        counter = 0
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) > 0:
                if firstname != row[0]:
                    updated_data.append(row)
                    counter += 1
                else:
                    contact_found = True

    if contact_found is True:
        with open(contact_database, "w") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(updated_data)
        print("Contact ", firstname, "deleted successfully")
    else:
        print("Contact not found in the list")

    input("Press any key to continue")

while True:
    contact_menu()

    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice == '1':
        add_contact()
    elif choice == '2':
        view_contacts()
    elif choice == '3':
        update_contact()
    elif choice == '4':
        delete_contact()
    else:
        break

print("-------------------------------")
print(" Thank you for using our system")
print("-------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is two questions. But first:

1. You can remove the `global` statements (the variables *are* already global to the function).
2. Also, these variables are used as constants, it is a convention to write them in UPPERCASE.
3. You are struggling with a lot of newlines: get rid of these and use the , `newline=""` as last parameter in your `open()` statements.

**Question 1: detect duplicate**

You could extend the add_contact function with a section that first checks for duplicates before it writes the entered data to file. For this you first must open the csv file as 'r' (read):

```
def add_contact():
    print("-------------------------")
    print("Add Contact Information")
    print("-------------------------")
    global contact_fields
    global contact_database

    # [ ['1','2'] ]
    contact_data = []
    for field in contact_fields:
        value = input("Enter " + field + ": ")
        contact_data.append(value)

    # check for duplicates
    with open(contact_database, "r", newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if row and row[0] == contact_data[0] and row[1] == contact_data[1]:
                print("{} {} already exists: '{}'".format(row[0], row[1], ' '.join(row)))
                return
            if row and row[2] == contact_data[2]:
                print("Duplicate {} '{}': in '{}'".format(contact_fields[2], row[2], ' '.join(row)))
                return
            if row and row[3] == contact_data[3]:
                print("Duplicate {} '{}' in '{}'".format(contact_fields[3], row[3], ' '.join(row)))
                return

    with open(contact_database, "a", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows([contact_data])

    print("Contact saved successfully")
    input("Press any key to continue")
    return
```

**Question 2: Sorting**

After `reader = csv.reader(f)`, `type(reader) == <class '_csv.rader'>` which behaves like an iterator. Once using reader as iterator in the for-loop, the iterator is done and you cannot iterate over it again. Therefore first store the rows, then sort, then iterate over the sorted rows. Like:

```
    with open(contact_database, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        rows = sorted([row for row in reader])   # rows = sorted list of all rows in reader
            for x in contact_fields:
            print(x, end='\t |')
        print("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------")

        for row in rows:                         # iterate over rows instead of reader
            for item in row:
                print(item, end="\t |")
            print("\n")
```